# How do I find the file path for an excel file on OneDrive that I'm trying to load into Jupyter Notebook using Python?

Tags: python

So my mentor wants me to figure out how to load, not download, a sample excel data set he emailed me using a cloud service. I saved it onto my OneDrive and I'm trying to figure out whether I need to find the file path for the code I'm trying to use or what. Here's what I'm experimenting with right now. Some advice would be wonderful!

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx?cid=7f625a276bc2326e&page=view&resid=7F625A276BC2326E!2139&parId=7F625A276BC2326E!113&app=Excel')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas can read in excel spreadsheets from a url, but the url should go directly to the file itself. (e.g. when you click on the link, it brings up the option to download, versus just taking you to a preview on your cloud sharing service.) see the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

microsoft has an example excel sheet on their website here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962

i ran this code successfully in a jupyter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962"
df = pd.read_excel(url)
```

Comment: Cool!! I was able to see the Microsoft example in my notebook as well. I'm just confused as to why it won't take the URL of the actual excel sheet on the OneDrive. Just gives me an error. Idk, maybe I'll try Google Drive? Hopefully it work from there.